# How to take statistic from map which is inside another map

Tags: java, java-stream

i need to find customers who paid most for specific category.
Information is inside this map Map<Customer, Map<Product, Long>> shopping.
Product have price and Long is quantity of Product.
For finisch i wanna map which look like that Map<Category, Customer>.

For beginning i wrote two methods

```
enter code here
   public Map<Customer, Map<Category, BigDecimal>> whoPaydMostPerCategory() {

        Map<Customer, Map<Category, BigDecimal>> collect = shopping.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey(), y -> pricePerCategory(y.getValue())));

        return collect;
    }

    public Map<Category, BigDecimal> pricePerCategory(Map<Product, Long> map) {

        return  map.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey().getCategory(),
                        y -> y.getKey().getPrice().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(y.getValue())), (a,b)-> a.add(b)));
    }
```

Soo whats next??

Comment: sort by values, take the first entry, get the category, reverse the map

Comment: I cant sort by values, because in Category is not only one. Example we can have category like AGD, RTV, FOOD ect. I need info who payd most for all different category separate.

Comment: `BigDecimal`s are being values to determine the most pricey one and to filter out the rest

Answer (score 0):

First, flatten the inner map entry with the customer to make a list of `[Customer, Category, BigDecimal]`. Then sorted by `price` reversely and use `Collectors.toMap` to collect as a map of `<Category, Customer>` where take the first `Customer` using the merge function.

```
whoPaydMostPerCategory()
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue()
                   .entrySet()
                   .stream()
                   .map(ee -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), ee)))
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue().getValue().negate()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getValue().getKey(), y -> y.getKey(), (a,b) -> a));
```